# firefox addon-sdk : handle http request timeout

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm building a firefox add-on using the add-on sdk. I need to make a http request to a certain page and I want to handle the connection timeout but couldn't find anything in the api: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/request.html

What I'm actually looking is a callback in case the client couldn't connect to the server.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SDK request will always call `onComplete`, when the request is considered done for the network. This means that `onComplete` is called in any case, disregarding if the request returned an error or a success.

In order to detect which error you've got, you need to check the Response object's (the object passed to the `onComplete` function) [property "status"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/request.html#status) (`response.status`). It holds the status code for the request. To look up status codes, consider the [list on the mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/HTTP_response_codes). If the response status is 0, the request has failed completely and the user is probably offline, or the target couldn't be reached.

A timeout would either be a status code 504 or 0. The implementation would be similar to this:

```js
var Request = require("sdk/request");

Request({
  url: "http://foo.bar/request.target",
  onComplete: function(response) {
    if(response.status==0||response.status==504) {
      // do connection timeout handling
    }
    // probably check for other status codes
    else {
      // assume the request went well
    }
  }
}).get();
```

I personally use a validation function on the request object, which returns me a number which depends whether I've got a correct response, an error from the web server or a connection issue (4xx and 0 status codes).