# Firefox Addon Request Module - onerror

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Does the request module in the Firefox add-on sdk have any option to specify a function that is to be executed if the request fails?If not,what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810790/firefox-addon-sdk-handle-http-request-timeout